# Openshift redirect no ssl

Tags: ssl, dns, openshift

I have an Openshift App at: http://web-brookelaw.rhcloud.com/

I have an alias for brookelaw.com to web-brookelaw.rhcloud.com on my dns setup at dnsimple

This is not working

I read the articles about dns and alais and I tried adding the alias www.brookelaw.com on openshift and I keep getting a redirect loop

I want to have either brookelaw.com or www.brookelaw.com resolve to my openshift app and I do not need SSL

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do custom domain names on OpenShift is by using `cname` records. For instance if I had an application at awesomeness-app.rhcloud.com and I wanted it be be awesomeness.com than I would do the following:

1. Create an alias for my application
   `rhc alias add awesomeness.com -a <yourappname>`
2. Then I would go to my DNS provider and create a cname record. Looks like you need to do the following for dnsimple:

> To use CNAME records, select CNAME from the Add Record drop down in
>   the advanced editor. Then enter the hostname you would like to alias
>   from and the fully-qualified domain name you would like to alias to.
>   You may also enter @ in the Alias for field to represent the domain
>   itself.
>
> For example, if the domain were example.com and you wanted
>   www.example.com to point to example.com you could put www in the name
>   field and @ in the alias for field.

If you want to forward over your whole domain, such as awesomeness.com and not www.awesomeness.com, then you either need to use Domain Forwarding or find a DNS provider that allows “Naked” CName records. Domain forwarding uses a web server to do a redirect.

Also the following forum thread might be helpful https://forums.openshift.com/domain-with-no-www-dns-question-is-that-possible.